# Why `wait $PID` returns immediately after SIGTERM signal is received, and not after $PID has actually terminated

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, posix

I have a use-case where a shell script runs a child process, and should **propgate any Termination Singals (SIGINT, SIGTERM, and SIGQUIT)** to the child process and **wait** for its termination, then terminate using the same exit code as the child process. In reality the script does more than that but I simplified it down to the werid use-case I am facing.

I noticed a weird behavior when using `wait` in a `sh` script.
The `wait $CHILD_PID` **will return the moment a Signal is recieved** by trap handler `_term`, to **actually wait** for the child to terminate **i have to do another** `wait $CHILD_PID`.

- The first wait returns status code `128 + Signal` (`130` in-case of using CTRL+C)
- The second wait returns status code that is returned by the CHILD Process (`12` in the example below).

**./signal-propagate**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

_term() {
  signal=$1
  echo " caught $signal, sending it to child pid $CHILD..."
  kill -$signal $CHILD 2>/dev/null
}

# register termination signals
trap "_term TERM" SIGTERM
trap "_term QUIT" SIGQUIT
trap "_term INT" SIGINT

# Start Command in BG
$@ &

# Get CHILD PID
CHILD=$!

# Wait for it to be finished
wait $CHILD
status=$?
echo "1 First Wait: child pid $CHILD exited with status $status"

wait $CHILD
status=$?
echo "2 Second wait: child pid $CHILD exited with status $status"

exit $status
```

Now try run a command that take sometime to terminate gracefully.
Here is an example, shamelessly using PHP

**work.php** (only handles SIGINT for brevity )

```php
<?php


function sig_handler($signo)
{
    echo "Signaler Handler Invoked! \n";
     switch ($signo) {
         case SIGINT:
            echo "Caught SIGINT CTRL-C...\n";
            echo "Shutdown Function Invoked, sleeping \n";
            sleep(5);
            echo "Shutdown Function done \n";
            exit(12);
            break;
         default:
     // handle all other signals
     }

}

// Enable Async Signal Handling
pcntl_async_signals(true);

// setup signal handlers
pcntl_signal(SIGINT,  "sig_handler");

echo "Doing some work... \n";
sleep(1000);

?>
```

Now try running

```
./signal-propagate php work.php
```

Output:

```
Doing some work...
^CSignaler Handler Invoked!
Caught SIGINT CTRL-C...
Shutdown Function Invoked, sleeping
command-loop caught INT, sending it to child pid 47270...
1 First Wait: child pid 47270 exited with status 130
Shutdown Function done
2 Second wait: child pid 47270 exited with status 12
```

I expect `wait` to wait until the process has terminated.

The [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wait.1p.html) says:

```
   If the wait utility is invoked with no operands, it shall wait
   until all process IDs known to the invoking shell have terminated
   and exit with a zero exit status.

   If one or more pid operands are specified that represent known
   process IDs, the wait utility shall wait until all of them have
   terminated. If one or more pid operands are specified that
   represent unknown process IDs, wait shall treat them as if they
   were known process IDs that exited with exit status 127. The exit
   status returned by the wait utility shall be the exit status of
   the process requested by the last pid operand.
```

However some literature about `wait` use a different statement, that `wait` will wait until the $PID state changes. but often give an example like `e.g when PID is terminated`.

EDIT:

- The script is simplified for brevity, the actual use-case includes running the $@ in a loop, unless it exits with a non-zero code, and a bunch of other cases. so the use of `exec` is not feasible.
- This was tested with `sh`, `bash` and `zsh`. However, this runs on minified container images that only have `sh` available.
- The behavior persists with SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, and SIGINT. Also it Persists when using ‘kill’ command to send signals (which unlike ctrl-c, doesn’t send signals to children, only to parent)

Comment: Note: You should use `bash` instead of `sh` for this.

Comment: Why not just `exec "$@"`?

Comment: @KamilCuk The script is simplified for brevity, the actual use-case includes running the $@ in a loop, unless it exits with a non-status code, and a bunch of other cases.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The actual use case runs on minified alpine container images that only have `sh` and `ash`.

Comment: @SherifAbdel-Naby Please [edit] your question to add the background information

Comment: When you press Ctrl-C, SIGINT is sent to all processes in the foreground process group, not just the `signal-propagate` script. So `work.php` receives the signal without you sending it with `kill` from the function.

Comment: @Barmar This point is true, but it doesn’t make a difference. If signal was sent to both processes, why one “wait” blocks and the other doesn’t? 

Also, the same behavior happen with SIGINT sent via kill command (which doesn’t propagate to children like CTRL-C does)… and the same behavior I am asking about happen with SIGTERM and SIGQUIT.

Comment: I thought there might have been different timing effects. Anyway, I think the reason is that the underlying `waitpid()` system call also returns when the process's state changes due to receiving a signal.

Comment: "why one “wait” blocks and the other doesn’t?" - the first "wait" terminated with code 130 (128+SIGINT), i.e. that's not 12 from a child, it's own termination despite the written "child exited" in echo output

Comment: @yvs2014 Why does the first "wait" terminate before the process actually terminates ?

Comment: "Why does the first "wait" terminate" - pressing 'ctrl-c' you terminated the first wait

Comment: @yvs2014 How do you explain the same behavior happening when you use `kill -s` that doesn't propagate signal to all children?

Comment: @SherifAbdel-Naby "How do you explain the same behavior happening when you use kill -s that doesn't propagate signal" - the received sigint interrupts shell (in the example its current command 'wait'), then sigint is sent to php child process from trap function. The only difference is that in the first case there's two sigints to php (one with process group and one from trap function)

Comment: Aside: `trap "_term TERM" SIGTERM` should be `trap "_term TERM" TERM`. With `trap "_term TERM" SIGTERM`, the Dash shell produces the error message `trap: SIGTERM: bad trap`.

Comment: From [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition, section 2.11](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11): "When the shell is waiting, by means of the *[wait](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/wait.html)* utility, for asynchronous commands to complete, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set shall cause the *wait* utility to return immediately with an exit status >128, immediately after which the trap associated with that signal shall be taken."

Comment: You could set a variable in the trap handler and check it after the first `wait` to decide if the `wait` exit status is due to the shell trapping the signal, or due to a child process terminating. That probably suffers from some race conditions though because you somehow need to distinguish whether the signal was caught before or during the execution of `wait`.

Comment: Probably the best solution is to attempt to kill the process with signal 0 after the first `wait` returns. If the kill is successful (meaning the child process still exists) you know that `wait` returned because it caught a signal. (But there is a very slim possibility that some other process got the same child pid immediately after it terminated.)